# CSS Transitions with jquery not working

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I have a jquery function that adds a class to a div, to hide it

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.control').click(function() {
        jQuery('.mob-nav').toggleClass('hide');
    });
});
```

This works fine, but now I want to add a transition to this, using CSS. So, I used

```
.hide { 
    -webkit-transition: all 2s cubic-bezier(0.04, 0.87, 0, 0.96);
    display: none;     
}
```

But it just won't work. I tried adding the transition to the div from the beginning. Also tried it on the whole body, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: You can’t use `display` with transitions, because it’s a non-animatable property. Use `visibility` instead. Also, please don’t rely on vendor prefixes (`-webkit-`); add the standard property.

Comment: `display` is not one of the properties you _can_ transition.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to animate the 'height' from 0 to auto, but that doesn't work either. So I resorted to animation max-height, from a fixed value, to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Display can not be transitioned. You can use this method instead:

```
jQuery('.mob-nav').hide(2000)
```

The argument to `hide()` is the transition time in miliseconds.
If you don't want use `hide()`, take a look at this answer:
[Transitions on the display property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property).